# Incremental exports from Amazon DynamoDB to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, analytics, amazon-athena

We need to run an analysis of the data in Amazon DynamoDB. Since doing it in the DDB isn't an option due to DDB's limitations with analysis, based on the recommendations I am leaning towards DDB -?> S3 -> Athena.

It is a data-heavy application with data streaming from AWS IoT devices and is also a multi-tenant application. Now, to sync data from DDB to Amazon S3, it will be probably a couple of times a day. How do we set up incremental exports for this purpose?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. For example, you could use AWS Data Pipeline or even DynamoDB streams. You should probably describe the use case a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Athena connector to be able to query your data in DynamoDB table directly using SQL query.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-prebuilt-data-connectors-dynamodb.html

https://dev.to/jdonboch/finally-dynamodb-support-in-aws-quicksight-sort-of-2lbl

Comment: this works but fails for large datasets (at least in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this use case is you can write an AWS Step Functions workflow that when invoked, can read data from an Amazon DynamoDB table and then format the data to the way you want it and place the data into an Amazon S3 bucket (an example that shows a similar use case will be available soon):

[image]

This is the reverse (here the source is an Amazon S3 bucket and the target is an Amazon DynamoDB table) but you can build the Workflow so the target is an Amazon S3 bucket. Because it's a workflow, you can use a Lambda function that is scheduled to fire a few times a day based on a CRON expression. The job of this Lambda function is to invoke the workflow using the Step Functions API.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I am more concerned about the incremental bit actually :). Is there an example for incremental export from Dynamo to any target?

Comment: TO handle the incrementat part -  you can create a scheduled event that invokes an AWS Lambda function by using an Amazon CloudWatch Event. Then you can use a CRON expression to schedule when the Lambda funciton is fired. You can use the AWS Step Functions API to invoke a workflow from the Lambda Function.  See here to learn how to use a  create a scheduled event -- https://github.com/scmacdon/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events

Answer (score 1):

#### ** Native Incremental Exports introduced in late 2023 **

DynamoDB gained an incremental export option in September 2023.  See the AWS Blog [Introducing incremental export from Amazon DynamoDB to Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-incremental-export-from-amazon-dynamodb-to-amazon-s3/).

The feature extends the existing [DynamoDB to S3 export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html) functionality, which previously supported only a full table export.  With the new incremental export, you can specify a from and to export time:

```bash
aws dynamodb export-table-to-point-in-time \
  --table-arn arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:ACCOUNT:table/TABLENAME \
  --s3-bucket BUCKET --s3-prefix PREFIX \
  --incremental-export-specification ExportFromTime=1693569600,ExportToTime=1693656000,ExportViewType=NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES \
  --export-type INCREMENTAL_EXPORT
```